# How can I make a code stop after the first if statement is true?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing some very basic coding, I have been playing around trying to create a code that generates a random value, and depending on that value posts a different message.
The problem is when the random value meets the condition for more "ifs" it posts all messages.
I've tried inserting "break" after each condition but I get "Invalid break statement".

```
const min=1;

let healthPoints=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))
console.log(`You currently have ${healthPoints} HP!`)


if (healthPoints<90){
    console.log("You're fine!")
}
if (healthPoints<50){
    console.log("You're not!")
}
if (healthPoints<10){
    console.log("You're f**ked")
}
```

This is what I get in console:

You currently have 46 HP!
You're fine!
You're not!

Comment: You can use a break in  condition. You can use a break in the loop

Comment: You can use a return statement in the condition when it will be fulfilled.

Comment: What is your expected output is healthPoints = 5 ?

Comment: You cannot use a break in an `if` statement, but you can use it in a `switch` statement. Returning inside a condition isn't great for legibility.  @Kyojimaru's answer will solve your problem gracefully.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to check the statement continually, you need to use `else if` not just `if` like this

```
const min=1;

let healthPoints=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))
console.log(`You currently have ${healthPoints} HP!`)


if (healthPoints<90){
    console.log("You're fine!")
}
else if (healthPoints<50){
    console.log("You're not!")
}
else if (healthPoints<10){
    console.log("You're f**ked")
}
```

Therefore, you will check first if `HP` < 90, if yes, it will log `You're fine!`, and since the condition is met, it won't check further for the `else if` statement

**Edit**: After re-reading your code, you need to change the logic like this

1. Is the health < 10? If yes, print `X`, if not then continue check other condition
2. Is the health < 50? If yes, print `Y`, if not then continue check other condition
3. Is the health < 90? If yes, print `Z`

which will change your code to

```
if (healthPoints<10){
    console.log("You're f**ked")
}
else if (healthPoints<50){
    console.log("You're not!")
}
else if (healthPoints<90){
    console.log("You're fine!")
}
```

Because if you check it from `< 90` first then it will hit true when the `HP` is even 1 then you'll never get to other statement, so you need to check if it's `< 10` first

Answer (score 2):

You can try using if/else statement. Plus i would suggest you to look at your conditions' sequence carefully. because i think you have to reverse them to get desired result.

```
const min=1;

let healthPoints=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))
console.log(`You currently have ${healthPoints} HP!`)


if (healthPoints<10){
    console.log("You're f**ked")
} else if (healthPoints<50){
    console.log("You're not!")
} else if (healthPoints<90){
   console.log("You're fine!")
}
```

Or you can put your logic inside a function and return the function when it meets certain condition.

```
function healthPointGenerator() {
    const min=1;
    
    let healthPoints=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))
    console.log(`You currently have ${healthPoints} HP!`)

    if (healthPoints<10){
        console.log("You're f**ked")
        return
    }
    
    if (healthPoints<50){
        console.log("You're not!")
        return
    }
    
    if (healthPoints<90){
        console.log("You're fine!")
        return
    }
   
   
 }
 healthPointGenerator(); //call the function here
```